# How do I expose an imported trait from the struct that derives it?

Tags: rust, traits, clap

I have a file called my_args.rs and it goes something like this.

```rust
use clap::Parser;

#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
#[command(author, version, about)]
struct MyArgs(){
...
}
```

and in main.rs

```rust
use crate::my_args::MyArgs;

pub fn main(){
// parse args
let args = MyArgs::parse();
}
```

I get a compilation error that tells me I should add "use clap::Parser;" to my main.rs too.

It worked when I followed its suggestion.

But what about if I wanted to ship MyArgs to be used by other people, how are they supposed to know that it is a clap parser?

Is there a way I can exposed the derived Parser trait through the struct that derives it?

Comment: This applies to all traits, not just derived ones: the call site must have the trait in scope. If your caller also depends on the same version of `clap`, they can import the `Parser` trait from there; or, you can expose your version of the `Parser` trait by `pub use`ing it; or, you can also expose trait methods by creating inherent methods of the same signature that forward to them (and then they won't have to `use` the trait).